# Game on the tree, cutting branch

Tags: algorithm, tree, game-theory

We have a forest of rooted trees. Two players makes alternating moves according to the following rule: one move is to cut vertex and all its children. Player which makes last move (no vertices remain) wins.

How can we compute Grundy function for the positions in the game?

Suppose we have a trees and we need to say whether current position is winning or losing?

Comment: Sounds very difficult homework!

Comment: I suggest you get a copy of "Winning Ways" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winning_Ways_for_your_Mathematical_Plays from your local library and work it out for yourself.

Comment: I admit that this problem is computer-sciency, however it falls more in the mathematical-category than in the programming-category. So you might find more help here:

> http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I hope this isn't for http://www.codechef.com/MARCH11/problems/SQUAGAME - because thats a currently running contest.

Comment: Isn't this just a variation of Nim? Each tree can be replaced by a heap with as many stones as the longest path in that tree.

Comment: Seeing as it's homework, shouldn't you be working that out yourself?  Generally homework is assigned after you're given the proper tools to complete the job.  I'm with eznme, though.  You should consider asking it in a different forum.

Comment: Should this be asked in gaming.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 5):

This is the [Hackenbush](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hackenbush) game. I highly recommend [this article](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tom/Game_Theory/comb.pdf), which covers Grundy numbers with great clarity and thoroughly discusses hackenbush toward the end.